# Unable to change database

Tags: php, database

My aim to is to Update Value in Database By using **Update Query** . On my **first page** i have just displayed database table in webpage. Then by using hyperlink i have to click on **Edit** to **second page** "edit.php".While on first page i have to get the value of **id** and send it to second page. Where a input form is displayed which gets Value casually but **Id** through hidden tag. On third page getting the values query is implented but the value of **id** is missing.

### First Page

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Assignment</title>
 </head>

<body>
 <?php
     $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     // Check connection
    if (!mysql_connect()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
    }
     $db=mysql_select_db("assignment",$con);

     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teacher ",$con);
    ?><table cellpadding="2px" border="2px"><?php
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     ?> <tr>
          <td><a href="edit.php?id=<?php       
        echo $row['id'];  ?>">Edit</a > <a href="delete.php">Delete</a>
                 </td><td>
             <?php       
        echo $row['id'];  ?></td><td> <?php echo $row['name'];?></td><td><?php echo $row['program']; ?></td>
               <?php   }
          ?></table><?php
    mysql_close($con);
 ?>

</body>
</html>
```

### Secnod Page edit.php

```
<html>
<head>
      <title>Assignment Edit</title>
    </head>
<body>
 <?php
    $id = $_GET['id'];
 ?>
    <form action="update.php" method="get">
       Address <input type="text" name="program"><br>
       <input type="hidden" name="id" value='<?php $id?>'>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

</body> 
</html>
```

### Third Page update.php

```
<html>
<head>
      <title>Update Page</title>
      </head>

      <body>

  <?php
       $add=$_GET['program'];
       $id=$_GET['id'];
       $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
     // Check connection
       if (!mysql_connect()) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
        }
       $db=mysql_select_db("assignment",$con);
        $query = "UPDATE teacher SET program='$add' WHERE id =".$id;
        echo $query;
       $result = mysql_query($query,$con);

      /* while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
          echo $row['id'] ." " .  $row['name']." ".  $row['address']."<br>"; 
               }
       mysql_close($con);
  */
  ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

### output

UPDATE teacher SET program='openSource' WHERE id =

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and use `var_dump();` to track what's set or not.

Comment: I don't see why you're using `$db` if you're not using it anywhere. Remove them.

Comment: are you talking about all page ...??

Comment: then how can i select the database ?

Comment: Ok, I think I know what it is. In your edit.php file, this `value='<?php $id?>'>` change it to `value='<?php echo $id ?>'>` try that.

Comment: it here id value is recieved but on update.php the url is    **http://localhost/osd/asign4/update.php?program=Algorithum&id=&submit=Submit**

Comment: `<?php echo $id?>` or `<?=$id?>`

Comment: localhost/osd/asign4/update.php?program=Algorithum&id=&submit=Submit this is the url you see id= nothing is i give the value manually in the link then the query is executed.

Comment: no the id value is not received here http://localhost/osd/asign4/update.php?program=Algorithum&id=&submit=Submit   See :: "id="

Comment: yes that is the problem souvickcse

Comment: Your code works with what I said about the hidden echo. **10 mins. ago**

Comment: I though that you are just trying print the "Id". Don't be angry i am again sorry that i miss interpret you.

Comment: I'm not angry, I told you what to do to fix it. Even though an element is hidden, the form's element still needs to be echo'ed, which I "explained" rather than just a "throw in code" type of answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to change this

```
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value='<?php $id?>'>
```

to

```
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value='<?php echo $id?>'>
```

(or)

```
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value='<?=$id?>'>
```

Comment: [`I answered this already`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23713593/unable-to-change-database#comment36444119_23713593)

Comment: I got this bro this ends my problem. Sorry Fred -ii-  i was unable to interpret that. Thanks a lot Fred -ii- and user790454.>

Comment: You should have told me to make it an answer. This was put in way after what I told you to do. @geek3150227 people come in and use comments that will solve the problem in order to make it their own.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes fred,but honestly i didn't noticed your answer,i just saw the question and posted the comment and answer

Comment: i was busy with the other posts